# Google Maps Location Sharing: Visible on Android but not in Browser

Tags: google-maps

When opening the Android app for Google Maps I see my friends sharing their location. They are also shown even if they are not actively sharing (or not online).

However, when I open my browser and go to https://www.google.com/maps/ click on the Menu, then "Location Sharing", I do not see anyone:

[image: 2017-12-30 Google Maps Location Sharing Issue]

Is that a bug? Or do they have to be online to show up in the browser? Maybe I am missing something.